# convert my list has unicode string which I 'm not be able replace in python

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

I have a list like this

```
[((u'Sylvester Miniter', u'Gillian Miniter'), 110)]
```

I need to to get it in a way like in python

```
[(('Sylvester Miniter', 'Gillian Miniter'), 110)]
```

have strip multiple operation but not able to do it. Please help

Comment: What are you trying to do? You want to convert the strings to ASCII or another encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Use str() to convert individual string to normal string.

```
>>> foo = u'Sylvester Miniter'
>>> foo
u'Sylvester Miniter'
>>> str(foo)
'Sylvester Miniter'
>>>
```

If you want to convert unicode string to ascii

```
>>> foo.encode('ascii')
'Sylvester Miniter'
```

Unicode to utf-8

```
>>> foo.encode('utf-8')
'Sylvester Miniter'
```